# How to get dynamic permissions for ACL

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I'm trying to implement dynamic permissions, that is to say, that the components to which the user has access come in the token.

I have looked at the documentation and in GitHub but I have not been able to achieve it.

Can someone guide me, please

https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/656

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, so please share your [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or update your question with other effort you made.

Comment: https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/656#issuecomment-417356900